# Fields become red before I start typing

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

The problem is that fields are validated before I start typing. When I open the  page that consists all fields from screenshot, fields are already red.
I posted snippets of html and type script code because all fields look the same. 
I will be very grateful for the help.

[image]

```js
primaryFormGroup = new FormGroup({});
  primaryFirstName = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
  
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {

    this.primaryFormGroup.addControl('primaryFirstName', this.primaryFirstName);
    this.formGroupPersonalInfo.addControl('primaryFormGroup', this.primaryFormGroup);
    
  }
```

```html
Html

<div fxLayout="column" fxLayout.gt-sm="row" fxLayoutGap="10px">
  <mat-form-field fxFlex="25">
    <input matInput name="primaryfirstname" fuse-letters-only-format [formControl]="primaryFirstName" [attr.data-name]="sel_primary_firstname_input" [(ngModel)]="applicationService.application.primaryPersonalInfo.firstName"
      placeholder="First name" maxlength="12" minlength="1" required (change)="personalInfoService.searchForWordTest($event)">
    <mat-hint align="end">{{primaryFirstName.value?.length || 0}} / 12</mat-hint>
    <mat-error *ngIf="primaryFirstName.hasError('required')">
      <div [attr.data-name]="sel_primary_firstname_req_errmsg">First name field is required.</div>
      <div fxLayoutAlign="end start" fxFlex>{{primaryFirstName.value?.length || 0}} / 12</div>
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Comment: why are you using ``[(ngModel)]`` when you've used ``formControl``?

Comment: To be sure that doesn't happen change your *ngIf to: !primaryFirstName.pristine && primaryFirstName.hasError('required')

Answer (score 1):

You should also check if it is touched before showing error.

```
<mat-error *ngIf="primaryFirstName.hasError('required') && primaryFirstName.touched">
```

Comment: It hides error message but fields are still highlighted in red color. https://prnt.sc/lljuot

Comment: Ok... u dont hv to use `formcontrol` with `[(ngModel)]`

Comment: i fixed it but it did not help

Comment: Good for u.  Thanks.